# Reusing update and create forms Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am trying to only use one form for my create and update forms. It is a simple form that I only use HTML with. Not the `FORM`collection. However, I am not sure of the best set up for this. Because in my edit form I have values called in the form of an Eloquent model that's inside a variable. I also need to use the `old` method in order to retrieve the old input. Would it be easier to just use the FORM collection? Or is there a clean way to achieve this without it?

**My form partial:**

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ action('\Modules\Pages\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@postEdit', ['id' => $page->id]) }}" class="uk-form">
    @include('pages::cms.partials.form.error')
    @include('pages::cms.partials.form.form')
</form>
```

**Related form element for create:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="URL" name="url" value="{{ old('url') }}">
```

**Related form element for update**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="URL" name="url" disabled value="{{ $page->slug }}">
```

So, basically I am trying to find the best way to combine these. If I just try to add `$page->slug` it would work on the update form but not the create form because the variable does not exist since it's only being called from the getUpdate method.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the laravelcollective Form package? Are you prohibited to do so? Because I've solved similar problem with laravelcollective's Form package.

Comment: I'm not prohibited from doing so. If I was to use it how could I achieve the results I want?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I solved this using the [laravelcollective](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) `Form` package:

Check if a model is present - *note: you can use other variable name than `$model`*. If it's present, use the `Form::model()` method so the form's inputs are populated by the model's properties (or the old inputs if you submitted the form and encountered validation errors).

```
@if (isset($model))
    {!! Form::model($model, ['route' => ['my.update.route', $model->id], 'method' => 'put']) !!}
@else
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'my.store.route']) !!}
@endif
```

So in your controller, you can do: `return view('my.input.view');` without passing a data if you want to a `create` and `return view('my.input.view', compact('model));` if you want to do an `update`.

Of course, you'll need to use the `Form` package's input methods: `{!! Form::text('property_name') !!}`, etc. for the population to work.

It's really good. It even populates related models as long as they're loaded: `{!! Form::text('related_model[related_model_property]') !!}`